# How can I add a featured thumbnail into a div via a data-image-src?

Tags: thumbnails

I am using [parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) and this is how It gets added. It works fine when I direct link to an image, but I would like each post's featured image to display here instead.

```
<div id="featured" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0.1" data-natural-width="2304" data-natural-height="1536" data-ios-fix="true" data-position="top" data-bleed="10" data-image-src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">
```

Your help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a friend for help and solved it like this

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'NAME_OF_THE_THUMBNAIL_KIND' ); $url = $thumb['0']; ?>

<div id="featured" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0.1" data-natural-width="2304" data-natural-height="1536" data-ios-fix="true" data-position="top" data-bleed="10" data-image-src="<?php echo $url ?>">
```